# https 301 redirect and sub domains not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I use the following code to redirect my http to https in htaccess.
the following code works perfectly fine in redirecting me to https version.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

But now when I create a sub domain, http://example.domain.com is also redirecting to https://www.domain.com.. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```